# ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am training a model with the following summary using tf.keras:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 28, 28, 20)        520       
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 15680)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 5)                 78405     
=================================================================
Total params: 78,925
Trainable params: 78,925
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

I am calling the fit method using

`model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, steps_per_epoch=125, epochs=5, use_multiprocessing=True)`

where X_train is a tensorflow Variable with shape [900000,32,32,1].

I am running into the following error:

```
Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[900000,28,28,20] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[{{node conv2d_1/Conv2D}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

     [[metrics_2/acc/Identity/_53]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

  (1) Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[900000,28,28,20] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[{{node conv2d_1/Conv2D}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

I am unable to understand why it's allocating a tensor with shape [900000,28,28,20] when the batch size is 32. I was expecting [32,28,28,20].

---

Full code:

```
IMAGE_SIZE = 32
BATCH_SIZE = 32

conv1_layer = keras.layers.Conv2D(input_shape=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 1), filters=20, kernel_size=[5, 5], activation='relu')
f = keras.layers.Flatten()
output_layer = keras.layers.Dense(units=5, activation='softmax')

model = keras.models.Sequential(layers=[conv1_layer, f, output_layer])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, steps_per_epoch=int(X_train.shape[0])//BATCH_SIZE, epochs=5, use_multiprocessing=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem's most likely in `use_multiprocessing=True`, which expects inputs as a generator object (see [docs](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit)) - so if feeding the `X_train` array doesn't immediately yield an error, it may be treating it as a generator by iterating over axis 0 and feeding all 900,000 samples at once - thus the error. Try `use_multiprocessing=False`, or feed your data with a [generator](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly).

Also, `steps_per_epoch` may be an additional source - omit them from `fit` - then, *evaluate* your `tf.Variable` inputs before passing them in, as `fit` doesn't handle that automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

`IMAGE_SIZE` is 32. 28 is the output shape after using a kernel of shape (5,5).

I tried option 1. `batch_shape` is not accepted as a parameter by Conv2D function but I created a separate input layer with your suggestion. I expected this to work since batch size gets explicitly mentioned but it throws the same error. Will try option 2.

Comment: @Rahul Then I'm surprised the model doesn't fail before memory does - your `Input` accepts batch slices of shape `(32, 28, 28, 20)`, but you're feeding it `(32, 32, 32, 20)` - this won't work properly. Also you stated, "I was expecting [32,28,28,20]", which doesn't happen if `IMAGE_SIZE` is 32.

Comment: Input shape is (32, 32, 32, 1) and output of conv layer is expected to be (32, 28, 28, 20).

Comment: @Rahul Nevermind, my mistake - the problem's most likely `use_multiprocessing=True`, which expects inputs from a _generator_ object (see [docs](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit)); if no exception is raised to that end, it may be treating `X_train` as the generator, thus feeding all 900,000 samples at once in parallel. Have you tried `use_multiprocessing=False`?

Comment: Removed multiprocessing parameter (false by default). Still doesn't work. Option 2 of changing config didn't work either. Not sure why it's allocating the tensor that way.

Comment: @Rahul Try removing the `steps_per_epoch` argument (multiprocessing still off). If nothing, pass `X_train[:64], y_train[:64]` to `fit` and see what happens. Lastly, what is the output of `print(model.layers[0].output.shape)`?

Comment: It expects the `steps_per_epoch` when using data tensors as input. Everything works as expected when using a small set of samples (like 64). Output shape of conv layer is (?, 28, 28, 20).

Comment: @Rahul I've noted users use `fit_generator` for `tf.Variable` inputs, but never `fit` - unsure if latter's compatible. If you somehow depend on the functionality of `fit`, an indirect solution is to pass `[:32]` slices at a time in a loop, and manually manage shuffling / epoch ends - though I don't claim it can't be done with `fit`, and welcome anyone else to show it.

Comment: Got it working!!! I removed steps_per_epoch as suggested but I evaluated the input tensors this time. Thanks for your help. Can you modify your answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @Rahul Yeah, I was about to suggest that - nicely done. I'll update the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to write your own training data generator or `keras.utils.Sequence`. Directly feed the entire training data is not a good idea especially when your dataset is very large. In additionally, **`use_multiprocessing` argument is used for generator or  keras.utils.Sequence input only** as explained in [.fit() doc](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit)

The following code is adapted from [A detailed example of how to use data generators with Keras](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly).

```py
import numpy as np
import keras

class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    'Generates data for Keras'
    def __init__(self, list_IDs, labels, batch_size=32, dim=(32,32), n_channels=1, n_classes=10, shuffle=True):
        'Initialization'
        self.dim = dim
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.labels = labels
        self.list_IDs = list_IDs
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end()

    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
        return int(np.floor(len(self.list_IDs) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generate one batch of data'
        # Generate indexes of the batch
        indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]

        # Find list of IDs
        list_IDs_temp = [self.list_IDs[k] for k in indexes]

        # Generate data
        X, y = self.__data_generation(list_IDs_temp)

        return X, y

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        'Updates indexes after each epoch'
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.list_IDs))
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def __data_generation(self, list_IDs_temp):
        'Generates data containing batch_size samples' # X : (n_samples, *dim, n_channels)
        # Initialization
        X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.n_channels))
        y = np.empty((self.batch_size), dtype=int)

        # Generate data
        for i, ID in enumerate(list_IDs_temp):
            # Store sample
            X[i,] = np.load('data/' + ID + '.npy')

            # Store class
            y[i] = self.labels[ID]

        return X, keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=self.n_classes)

params = {'dim': (32,32),
          'batch_size': 32,
          'n_classes': 5,
          'n_channels': 1,
          'shuffle': True}

train_data_path = # (list of string) ['0302','0325','3103',...] 'data/0302.npy' is the path where stores the '0302' image. 
train_labels = # (list of int) [1,0,4,...] corresponding labels of 900,000 images.

# Generators
train_gen = DataGenerator(train_data_path, train_labels, **params)

model.fit_generator(generator=train_gen,
                    epochs=5,
                    use_multiprocessing=True,
                    workers=2)
```